# Live Template for Java in intellij IDEA does not behave correctly in block comments?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

I am defining my own live template and it seems that the behaviour is faulty when using (dependent) variables inside block comments (not tested for line comments).

My template:

```
$commentStart$*
* Repository to handle {@link  $ClassName$} entities.
$commentEnd$
@DDD.Repository
public interface $EntityName$Repository {
    $commentStart$*
     * Persists the given instance
     * @param $entityName$
     * to persist
     * @return the given {@code $entityName$}
    $commentEnd$
    $ClassName$ save($ClassName$ $entityName$);
    
    $END$
}
```

With the following variables:

[image: Defined Variables]

The template works as expected if I leave all block comments free of any variables. Also, I'm pretty sure that the variable `ClassName` shouldn't be necessary.

I tried several variations, such as removing `blockCommentStart()` and simply using `/**` (and  with `end` respectively). I tried using the same variable in all code places but nothing makes the template work if the variables are embedded in the comments.
I exepected the template to evaluate variables according to their expressions and insert them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it with a file template:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
/**
 * Repository to handle {@link ${NAME}} entities.
 *
 * @see ${NAME}
 */
 @DDD.Repository
public interface ${NAME}Repository {

    #set($arg = $NAME.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + $NAME.substring(1))
    /**
     * Persists the given instance.
     *
     * @param ${arg} 
     *            the entity to persist
     *
     * @return the given {@code ${arg}}
     */
    ${NAME} save(${NAME} ${arg});
}
```